# Problem starting my virtual environment with python + FastAPPI + Uvcnicorn

Tags: python-3.x, fastapi, gunicorn

I have a problem starting my first virtual environment in Python using FastAPI with Uvnicorn.

Following the guide of FastAPI and having installed the full pack of FastAPI.

I get this error after introducing:

**uvicorn main:app --reload**
I've the next message: *'uvicorn: The term 'uvicorn' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.'*

I've read comments in this equipe of work and I tried with another way introducing in terminal :

```
python -m uvicorn main:app --reload
```

In that case the error was different:

*INFO:     Will watch for changes in these directories: ['C:\Users\Ivan\OneDrive\Escritorio\Univcorn']
*INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)*
*INFO:     Started reloader process [14496] using WatchFiles*
*ERROR:    Error loading ASGI app. Could not import module "main".**

The name of the file is 'main.py' an the object that I calling is 'app.

Someone here had the same problem or can help me to resolve?

Thanks, Ivan

Comment: If you have fastapi and uvicorn installed in a virtual environment, you should use the command `.\venv\Scripts\python.exe <commands>`